# Detect window restore operation is about to begin

Tags: multithreading, winapi, event-handling, directx

`WM_GETMINMAXINFO` is generated when maximize operation is about to begin and `WM_SIZE` when maximize operation is finished.

`WM_SIZE` is also generated when restore operation is finished.

**But how to detect window restore operation is about to begin?**

---

I need detect exact moment when window is about to restore , but not the moment when already restored. I am developing multithread `DirectX` application. I render in dedicated secondary thread. When window is about to begin maximize or restore I need to change render back buffer size (`DirectX Device` `Reset`). I can resize back buffer only from main thread so I use `Critical Sections` to sync with render thread. The problem is that I cant interrupt `Present` operation in render thread and when maximize or restore operation is about to begin I wait until current `Present` operation is finished and only then begin to resize (maximize / restore). If you change back buffer size too late (when maximize / restore operation is finished (`WM_SIZE` message) you can notice old frame is drawn with wrong size (image is stretched).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it is nice to see that someone is still ponder over such issues. This small things, like one-second image stretching when resizing, distinguish a professional looking application from bedroom coded one.

In my old code I found tricks that probably will be interesting to you.
A first thing is that you can check `WM_SYSCOMMAND`:

```
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
           {
               switch (wParam)
               {
               case SC_MAXIMIZE:
                   std::cout << "Going to MAXIMIZE: " << std::endl;
                   break;

               case SC_MINIMIZE:
                   std::cout << "Going to MINIMIZE: " << std::endl;

                   break;

               case SC_RESTORE:
                   std::cout << "Going to RESTORE: " << std::endl;
                   break;


               default:
                   break;
               }
               return DefWindowProc(m_hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
           }
```

But the problem is that it don't catch maximize / restore events when user *double-clicks titlebar*.

So I found a little trick, when parse `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`.

First let's do a little fun research. We read docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where we found that:

> WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message sent to a window whose size, position, or place in the Z order is *ABOUT to change*

Because it is nearly impossible to debug events in common debugger (how would you test if debugger often changes z-order of window?), so for testing purposes we will make a little console app  with `int main()`, where we initialize a window as usual (HINSTANCE we can get from `GetModuleHandle(0);`). So we have a console and a window at same time. In window procedure we catch `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and print info, it will tell us, to console:

```
        case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
        {
            WINDOWPOS* wp = ((WINDOWPOS*)lParam);

            // We checking current state which is saved in member (or global) bools
            // Set them checking WM_SIZE before
            if (m_bMaximized)
            {
                std::cout << "Currently MAXIMIZED: ";
            }
            else if (m_bMinimized)
            {
                std::cout << "Currently MINIMIZED: ";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Currently NORMAL: ";
            }

            dbgPrintPositionCurrent();

            std::cout << "Going to change to: ";
            dbgPrintPosition(wp->x, wp->y, wp->cx, wp->cy, wp->flags);
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

            return DefWindowProc(m_hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

See utility functions [here](http://pastebin.com/jAh4pDk6).

When we played enough we can now make it useful:

```
                bool bFrameChanged = ((wp->flags) & SWP_FRAMECHANGED) > 0;
            bool bNoCopyBits = ((wp->flags) & SWP_NOCOPYBITS) > 0;
            bool bNormal = (!m_bMaximized) && (!m_bMinimized);

            // from maximized
            if(m_bMaximized && bFrameChanged && !bNoCopyBits)
            {
                std::cout << " MAXIMIZED -> NORMAL " << std::endl;
            }
            if (m_bMaximized && bFrameChanged && bNoCopyBits)
            {
                std::cout << " MAXIMIZED -> MINIMIZED " << std::endl;
            }

            // from normal states
            if (bNormal && bFrameChanged && !bNoCopyBits)
            {
                std::cout << " NORMAL -> MAXIMIZED " << std::endl;
            }
            if (bNormal && bFrameChanged && bNoCopyBits)
            {
                std::cout << " NORMAL -> MINIMIZED"  << std::endl;
            }

            // from minimized
            if(m_bMinimized && bFrameChanged)
            {
                std::cout << " MINIMIZED -> MAXIMIZED " << std::endl;
            }
            if(m_bMinimized && m_bMaximized && bFrameChanged)
            {
                std::cout << " MINIMIZED -> MAXIMIZED " << std::endl;
            }


            return DefWindowProc(m_hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

I'm really not sure that is it a simplest or even is it right way to do this. But it works for now =)
Also, I think your app dont'care what *exactly* happened: maximizing, restoration or resizing. It just cares if size *has changed*, so you need to resize your buffers / recreate swap chain etc...

Hope it helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks you just literally safe my life :) Because im also was playing with WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING. WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, WM_WINDOWACTIVATE and this was just crazy, nothing work but i was close, when remove platform toolbar and make a blank window with my custom window toolbar + custom controls on it.