# Prevent exiting maximized window mode

Tags: c, winapi, window, mode, maximize-window

I'm writing window managing code in C. When certain flags are set, I want to have a maximized window that cannot be resized by dragging the window by the title bar. Is there a way to 'lock' a maximized window in its maximized state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    if(IsMaximized(hwnd) && ((wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_RESTORE || (wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MOVE)){
        return 0;
    }

    break;
```

Edit

The complete code

```
switch(message){ //handle the messages
    ...
    ...
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
        ...
        break;
    ....
    default:   //for messages that we don't deal with
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

This is the default *WindowProcedure*. I thought it was known.

valter

Comment: This almost worked, I've made a little adjustment. I'm checking for SC_MOVE instead of SC_RESTORE, in the following way: `if(((wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MOVE) && (style & WS_MAXIMIZE)) return 0;`. It's also important to return DefWindowProc when not returning zero, otherwise all other syscommands will be ignored. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

valter's answer shows how to intercept user action and cancel window state change at that stage. This however will not handle state changes made though Win API directly (e.g. `ShowWindow`).

Windows API offers you another option which provides finer control of window state/position changes. It is also more flexible: for example, it allows apply application-defined constraints on window position. The option is [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653) message and it's handler. The window receives a pointer to structure it can modify to adjust desired state and position. Forcing maximized state there hence handles wider range of scenarios.

> While this message is being processed, modifying any of the values in WINDOWPOS affects the window's new size, position, or place in the Z order. An application can prevent changes to the window by setting or clearing the appropriate bits in the flags member of WINDOWPOS.

You can also read up on this message on Raymond Chen's blog: [Use WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING to intercept window state changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/16/7123299.aspx).

There are also a few questions here on SO as well, this one looks close to yours and the answer also provides a code snippet as well: [Detect window restore operation is about to begin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204488/detect-window-restore-operation-is-about-to-begin/16209626#16209626)